# Is it possible to disable Google Chat Markdown formatting?

Tags: google-chat

Is it possible to post text in Google Chat without it being interpreted as Markdown formatting?  For example typing `*John*` is converted to *`John`*

Escaping characters with `\` doesn't seem to work.

I haven't found a way to change it in the settings or in the Google Chat documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any documented way to turn off Markdown support.

You can avoid bolding and italicizing by enclosing text in backquotes <kbd>`</kbd> located on the tilde <kbd>~</kbd> key of US keyboards and in the `=\<` page of the Android on-screen keyboard.  Backquotes create a "code span" around their contents which are not parsed as Markdown but displayed as literal text and rendered in a monospace font.

Far from a perfect solution, but it's at least a barely-tolerable way to send mathematical formulae, globs/regular expressions, etc. in a Chat message.